# Mongo:the data consistency

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I have some problem in my project.
I deploy mongodb service in 4 servers.TO be understandable,I make a simple code demo ,just as follows(run with django):

```
from mongoengine improt *

class Date(Document):

      name=StringField()
queryset=Date.object.filter(name="xxx")

num=queryset.count() // num=1777

for item in quertset:

      item.delete()
```

after several time , I run `num=Date.object.filter(name="xxx").count()`

the num is also 1777

but when I try to print every item in the queryset,it return NONE

is this data consistency problem in mongo?

Comment: It looks like you are deleting the items with your loop after getting the count.

Comment: yep,I deleted the items filter,but 讲道理(to be honest), I should get 0 when I run "Date.objects.filter(name="xxx").count()" for which I have deleted them.雪崩中.....